# Automatically counting and labelling the number of annotations in a Praat textgrid

Tags: praat

I am interested in studying animal vocalisations, and have labelled each vocalisation type in a sequence, using a Praat textgrid. I have already found a script to enable me toExtract the durations of each labelled interval. I would like to be able to create a second tier in my text grid in which the number of vocalisation labels is is counted successively from one, and then print the name of each vocalisation and its numerical position in the sequence.

Comment: Can you be more explicit? With some pictures, that could help to understand your aim.